# Why don't we use keywords like "let", "var" and "const" in function parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function myFunction(let name){
    console.log("hello "+name);
}

myFunction("adi");
```

The above code produces an error. Why?

Comment: It's the syntax of the language.

Comment: What would be the point? The difference between `let` and `var` is whether it's block scope or function scope. But for a function parameter they're the same thing.

Comment: in that respect, const could be useful though :p

Comment: Arguments are automatically declared internally.

Answer (score 4):

`let` and `const` are relatively new features in the language, they were added in EcmaScript 6. Prior to this, all variables were either global or local to the function. In the function body you declare local variables with `var`, but parameters are automatically local so there's no need for a keyword to distinguish them from global variables.

When `let` and `const` were added to the language, there was no need to change the way parameters are declared. The distinction between `let` and `var` is not useful: `let` is for declaring block-scoped variables, but the block for a function parameter is the same as the whole function. It might be useful to be able to declare a function parameter `const`, so you can't reassign it, but I guess the designers didn't feel it was useful enough to make this change to the syntax (they already made it more complex by adding destructuring and default values).

Comment: Unlike languages like C, variables and functions in JavaScript are not always declared at the point of use and instead can be hoisted to the top of their scope at runtime. key words "var" and "let" help the interpreter understand how to manage access to these variables. As function parameters are already at the top of their scope, they would be handled the same whether "var" or "let" was used, making it somewhat unnecessary to add the key word. I wrote a little post on hoisting here for context https://www.twistedbrackets.com/variable-and-function-hoisting/

Answer (score 2):

It is the way language works, and how its syntax is defined. However there must be a reason about it.

I can reason a little bit about it and share my reason.

There are two scope types in JavaScript,

1. Function scope,
2. Block scope

`var` defines a variable with Function scope whereas `let` and `const` define block scope variables.

Function parameters are in function scope, which makes sense, at least with the current mindset of the language since it does not make sense to pass a parameter to a function to be in scope in block. This would arise questions regarding ambiguities of the scope the parameters belong to, that would be overcome by having another syntax to maybe label parameters and blocks in a way. With another mindset of language designing that could be possible and even useful. However, the current state of the language is not like that and it makes sense in itself.

Also historically there was only `var`. `let` and `const` came way later than `var`, hence there was only function scope in the language and so the parameters had to be either in the global scope or in the function scope and it has designed to be in the function scope which is not unusual and very common in ALGOL-like languages. When `let` and `const` came one reason they came was having a block level scope other than function blocks, like `if` conditions, `for` etc. So they did not applied to the function parameters which is usually more useful when all visible in the their function.

Just to clarify what I meant about the hypothetical alternative scoping in an alternative universe, or parallel universe, JavaScript, I want to construct an example with yet another questions arisen to be answered:

```
function f(x:a, x:b, y:b) { // parameters' scope labeling syntax
    scope a: if(x > 1 && !y) return x + 1; // block's scope labeling syntax
    scope b: return x * y;

}

f(3:a, 9:b, 0:b) // returns 4
f(3:a, 9:b, 1:b) // returns 27
```